# How to set parent to get access to another form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

**I got 2 forms:**

`Input.vb` and `Writer.vb`

When `Input` was set as **default form**, I was able to do the following:

**In Writer.vb**

```
Input.mymessage = texter.Text
```

`texter` is btw an Textbox.

Since I needed to change the default form to another it does not work anymore.
How to fix that? Is there any "set parent" or "Dim Input as Input.Forms.all" way to get it work again?

Already tried `Dim Input as new Input`.

**Edit:**
I found the way of using `CType(Me.ParentForm, Input).mymessage = texter.Text`, but `Writer.Parent = Me` does not work for me :/

Comment: I am looking for something like "change textbox of parent form".

Comment: Or Raise an Event?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you have object *definitions* (classes), object *instances* of those classes, and variables that have *references* to those instances.

People tend to forget these things apply to forms, too.

When `Input` was set as the default form, VB.Net was giving you a default instance for the form, and a special global variable that refers to it with the same name as the class. So the name `Input` in your code could be one of two different things, depending on the context: the class type, or the special variable for the default instance of that class type.

Now that `Input` is not the default form, you're not using that default instance any more. When you show the form, you're creating your own instance. The same is true for the `Writer` form. You have a `Writer` class, but that's only the *definition* for an instance of the class you create somewhere. You need to provide this instance of your `Writer` form with a reference to the instance of the `Input` form that was created.

You do that the same way you handle object references with any other .Net class.

Comment: Joel, thx for ur explanation :) Is there any easier way? Like change it just for all Forms wth name `Input`? I mean the way of `For Each Input As Input In Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Input).Any`.

Answer (score 0):

When going one to another form, instead of using the "Private Sub" I use Public sub, it shares everything in that form to anything else trying to use it.